# keep post filter for single page loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like wordpress to keep the query filter inside the single page loop. For example when a user sorts by category X, the category page gets served with posts only from category X. However, when the user clicks in to the post and goes to the single page, the next post link will cycle through all posts.

Here is the code in single.php:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
        ...
                        <!-- pagination functions here. -->
                        <div class="nav-previous pull-left">
                            <?php next_post_link('%link', '<span class="hidden-xs btn-black btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Next Question </span><span class="visible-xs btn btn-black"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Next </span>'); // next post ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-next pull-right">
                            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="btn btn-black hidden-xs"> Previous Question <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span><span class="btn btn-black visible-xs"> Previous <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>'); // previous post ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <!-- pagination functions ends here -->
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <!-- comments template -->
                        <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script("comment-reply"); ?>
                        <?php comments_template(); // include comments.php ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <!-- end post-format -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I ensure that the_post() only returns posts in the category that the user searched for in category.php?

Comment: Why not store the filter in the session and then apply from session to all searches?

Comment: I am having trouble imagining what you mean. I can see how I would store the filter in the session. What do you mean by apply from the session to all searches?

Comment: The problem is that the next_post_link and previous_post_link doesn't preserve your filter.  I don't know much about wordpress or how to do it, but those functions looked at a filter they would preserver the user's position in the list as well as the filter that provided the list itself, so then the next filtered link could be linked to.

Comment: @DanFarrell sessions aren't the way to go here as Wordpress doesn't use sessions by default, check my answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just completed a very intensive post link function for the same exact thing during this week. This function does not use sessions, cookies or HTTP referrers for paging. I have also posted this on WPSE, so I'm just going to repost that post here.

### FEW PRE-NOTES

- I have this function written not just for categories, but for tags, taxonomies, authors and search queries. You can remove what you don't want
- By default, on any other page, when a single post is clicked, the next and previous posts will be from the same term, this you can disable as like in the usage part right at the bottom of the post
- This post should be read in conjunction with [this post on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/170007/31545)

### THE POST FROM WPSE

The original intention of this question was to know where a single post was referred from and then according to that serve up the next and previous post according to the post referrer

### What I wanted to accomplish was for eaxample:

A post is clicked on from a category, taxonomy, tag, search or author arhive page. These archives serves as referrers. Now, normally one would use, as in my question, `wp_get_referer()` to get that referrer and use that in further queries. As described by [@G.M. in his accepted answer above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170016/31545), this method has not reliable, so I went and used his **Alternative Solution**

The other problem was that, you need to use some kind of cookie or session to store this referrer to so that you still dish up posts from the original referrer when you navigate away from the original single post that was clicked from the specific archive. As cookies are also controlled by the end user and thus not reliable, and the fact that Wordpress does not use sessions by default, I refactored the next and previous post links using @G.M. **Alternative Solution** to have a reliable way of checking and storing my original referrer

This is what I came up with, and I hope someone will find it useful in the near future. Please, use and abuse the code to fit your needs, just one request, leave a link back to this question. :-)

### NOTES ON CODE TO FOLLOW

- This code is quite long and intensive, so I'm not going to go into details. The code has been well commented
- This code has the option to page between posts within the same term, just like the default `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` functions in Wordpress. Just like the native functions, you have to set the taxonomy. The default value for `in_same_term` is `true` and the taxonomy is `category`
- Most importantly, this code requires PHP 5.4+

### THE CODE

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Pieter Goosen
 * @license GPLv2 
 * @link http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * The functions on this page returns the next and previous post links
 * depending what is been set
 *
 * @return function single_post_navigation()
*/ 

/**
 * Register six new query variables aq, ,cq, tq, ttq, taq, and sq set by 
 * the term_referer_link function
 *
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars
 *
*/ 
add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'cq'; // Will hold category ID
    $vars[] = 'tq'; // Will hold taxonomy name
    $vars[] = 'ttq'; // Will hold term slug
    $vars[] = 'sq'; // Will hold search query
    $vars[] = 'aq'; // Will hold author name
    $vars[] = 'taq'; // Will hold tag id


    return $vars;

}, 10, 3 );

/**
 * Conditional tag to check whether or not a query_var has been set
 *
 * @param string $query_var query_var to check
 * @return (bool) true if query_var exists, false on failure
 *
*/
function has_query_var( $query_var ) {

    $array = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;

    return array_key_exists( $query_var, $array );

}

/**
 * For posts being clicked from a category page, the query_var, 'cq' is set. 
 * 'cq' holds the category ID
 *
 * Set two query_var, 'tq' and 'ttq' to single posts that was clicked on from 
 * taxonomy pages. 'tq' holds the taxonomy name while 'ttq' holds the term name
 *
 * For search queries, the query_var, 'sq' is set to single posts that was clicked on from 
 * the search page. 'sq' holds the search query value
 *
 * For posts being clicked from an author page, the query_var, 'aq' is set. 
 * 'aq' holds the author ID
 *
 * For posts being clicked from a tag page, the query_var, 'taq' is set. 
 * 'taq' holds the tag ID
 *
 * This function replaces the wp_get_referer() and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
 * functions that are not very reliable
 * @see php.net manual $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
 *
 * @uses add_query_arg()
 * @uses post_link
 * @uses post_type_link
 *
*/
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'term_referer_link', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_link', 'term_referer_link', 10, 3 );

function term_referer_link( $permalink, $post ) {

    switch ( true ) {

        case ( is_category() ):

            $category = get_queried_object_id();

            $args = [
                'cq'    => $category, 
            ];

            break;
        case ( is_tax() ):

            $term = get_queried_object();

            $args = [
                'tq'    => $term->taxonomy, 
                'ttq'   => $term->slug
            ];

            break;

        case ( is_search() ):

            $search = get_search_query();

            $args = [
                'sq'    => $search, 
            ];

            break;

        case ( is_author() ):

            $author = get_queried_object_id();

            $args = [
                'aq'    => $author,
            ];

            break;

        case ( is_tag() ):

            $tag = get_queried_object_id();

            $args = [
                'taq'   => $tag,
            ];

            break;

    }

    if( isset( $args ) ) { 

        $permalink  = add_query_arg( $args, $permalink );

    }

    return $permalink;

}

/**
 * @access private
 * This function is marked private and should not be used in any other functions
 *
 * This is a helper function for the main navigation function 
 * 
 * This function checks if any of the query variables is set in the single
 * post page URL. If they exists, the values are retrieved that was set
 * by the query variables
 *
 * This query variables is converted into query arguments for the query that will
 * be used to determine the current post position and the posts adjacent to the
 * current post which will translate in the next and previous post. 
 * 
 * When no query variables are present, and empty array of argument is returned
 * 
 * @uses has_query_var()
 * @return (array) $add_query_args_to_args Query variable to determine the next/previous post links
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg
 *
*/
function _query_vars_to_query_args() {

    switch ( true ) {

        case ( has_query_var( 'cq' ) ): // For category referrer

            $category = get_query_var( 'cq' );

            $add_query_args_to_args = [
                'cat' => $category,
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'tq' ) && has_query_var( 'ttq' ) ): // For taxonomy term referrer

            $taxonomy   = get_query_var( 'tq' );
            $term       = get_query_var( 'ttq' );

            $add_query_args_to_args = [
                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
                        'field'             => 'slug',
                        'terms'             => $term,
                        'include_children'  => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'sq' ) ): // For search referrer

            $search = get_query_var( 'sq' );

            $add_query_args_to_args = [
                's' => $search,
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'aq' ) ): // For author referrer

            $author = get_query_var( 'aq' );

            $add_query_args_to_args = [
                'author' => $author,
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'taq' ) ): // For tag referrer

            $tag = get_query_var( 'taq' );

            $add_query_args_to_args = [
                'tag_id' => $tag,
            ];

            break;

        default: // Default: returns empty array on any other archive or homepage

            $add_query_args_to_args = [];

            break;

    }

    return $add_query_args_to_args;

}
/**
 * @access private
 * This function is marked private and should not be used in any other functions
 *
 * This is a helper function for the main pagination function. This function 
 * checks if the defined query variables has been set in the URL of a single
 * post
 * 
 * If any of the query variables are found on any given single post page, then 
 * these query variables will be set to the next and previous post links according
 * to the single post's query variables
 * 
 * This way, next and previous posts will be shown from the same category, term, 
 * search query or author archive from which the original single post was referred 
 * from. 
 *
 * If a single post was referred from any other archive or main page, these query 
 * variables will not be set, and function will default to an empty array and no
 * query variables will be set to the next and previous post links
 *
 * @uses has_query_var()
 * @return (array) $qv Query variable to add to next/previous post links
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg
 *
 * @todo Other archives can be added later
*/
function _add_query_vars_to_nav_links() {

    switch ( true ) {

        case ( has_query_var( 'cq' ) ): // For category referrer

            $category = get_query_var( 'cq' );

            $qv = [
                'cq'    => $category, 
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'tq' ) && has_query_var( 'ttq' ) ): // For taxonomy term referrer

            $taxonomy   = get_query_var( 'tq' );
            $term       = get_query_var( 'ttq' );

            $qv = [
                'tq'    => $term->taxonomy, 
                'ttq'   => $term->slug
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'sq' ) ): // For search referrer

            $search = get_query_var( 'sq' );

            $qv = [
                'sq'    => $search, 
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'aq' ) ): // For author referrer

            $author = get_query_var( 'aq' );

            $qv = [
                'aq'    => $author,
            ];

            break;

        case ( has_query_var( 'taq' ) ): // For tag referrer

            $tag = get_query_var( 'taq' );

            $qv = [
                'taq'   => $tag,
            ];

            break;


        default: // Default: returns empty array on any other archive or homepage

            $qv = [];

            break;

    }

    return $qv;

}

/**
 * This function returns navigation links to the next/previous single post
 * There are choices to which taxonomy to use, and whether adjacent posts should
 * be of the same term or not
 * 
 * When in_same_term is set to true, you have a choice to use the parent term or
 * child term if a post belongs to both. If the parent term is not available, the child term 
 * is automatically used
 *
 * @param array $defaults An array of key => value arguments. Defaults below 
 * - bool in_same_term      Whether or not next/previous post should be in the same term Default true
 * - bool parent_term       If in_same_term is true, should the parent or child terms be used Default true
 * - string/array taxonomy  The taxonomy from which terms to use Default category
 * - string previous_text   Text to display with previous post Default 'Previous post'
 * - string next_text       Text to display with next post Default 'Next post'
 *
 * @return string $links
*/ 
function get_single_post_navigation( $args = [] ) {

    // Sets the default arguments for default usage
    $defaults = [
        'in_same_term'      => true,
        'parent_term'       => true,
        'post_types'         => '',
        'taxonomy'          => 'category',
        'previous_text'     => __( 'Previous post' ),
        'next_text'         => __( 'Next post' ),
    ];

    // Merges the default arguments with user defined variables
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    /**
     * Get the currently displayed single post. For this use 
     * get_queried_object() as this is more safe than the global $post
     *
     * The $post global is very easily changed by any poorly written custom query
     * or function, and is there for not reliable
     *
     * @see Post below on WPSE for explanation
     * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167706/31545
    */ 
    $single_post = get_queried_object();

    /**
     * Use the post type of the current post or post types entered in args
     *
    */ 
    $post_type   = ( empty( $args['post_types'] ) ) ? $single_post->post_type : $args['post_types'];


    // Set the variable query variables according to condition
    if( !empty( _query_vars_to_query_args() ) ) {

        $query_args = _query_vars_to_query_args(); 

    }elseif( true === $args['in_same_term'] ) {

        $terms =  wp_get_post_terms( $single_post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] ); 

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if( $term->parent === 0 ) {
                    $parent[] = $term;
                }else{
                    $child[] = $term;
                }
            }   

            $term_id = ( $args['parent_term'] === true && isset( $parent ) ) ? $parent[0]->term_id : $child[0]->term_id;

            $query_args = [ 
                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy'          => $args['taxonomy'],
                        'field'             => 'term_id',
                        'terms'             => $term_id,
                        'include_children'  => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

    }else{

        $query_args = [];

    }

    // Default arguments to use with all the conditional statements above
    $default_query_args = [ 
        'post_type'         => $post_type,
        'fields'            => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    ];

    // Merges the default arguments with the arguments from the conditional statement
    $combined_args = wp_parse_args( $query_args, $default_query_args );

    $q = new WP_Query( $combined_args );

    // Get the current post position. Will be used to determine adjacent posts
    $current_post_position = array_search( $single_post->ID, $q->posts );

    // Get the returned values from '_add_query_vars_to_nav_links()' to build links
    $get_qv = _add_query_vars_to_nav_links(); 

    // Get the next/older post ID
    if ( array_key_exists( $current_post_position + 1 , $q->posts ) ) {
        $next = $q->posts[$current_post_position + 1];
    }

    // Get post title link to the next post
    if( isset( $next ) ) {

        $next_post      = get_post( $next );
        $next_post_link = ( !empty( $get_qv ) ) ? add_query_arg( $get_qv, get_permalink( $next ) ) : get_permalink( $next );
        $next_title     = '<span class="meta-nav">' . $args['next_text'] . ': </span><a href="' . $next_post_link . '">' . $next_post->post_title . '</a></br>';

    }else{

        $next_title     = '';

    }

    // Get the previous/newer post ID
    if ( array_key_exists( $current_post_position - 1 , $q->posts ) ) {
        $previous = $q->posts[$current_post_position - 1];
    }

    // Get post title link to the previous post
    if( isset( $previous ) ) {

        $previous_post      = get_post( $previous );
        $previous_post_link = ( !empty( $get_qv ) ) ? add_query_arg( $get_qv, get_permalink( $previous ) ) : get_permalink( $previous );
        $previous_title     = '<span class="meta-nav">' . $args['previous_text'] . ': </span><a href="' . $previous_post_link . '">' . $previous_post->post_title . '</a></br>';

    }else{

        $previous_title     = '';

    }

    // Create the next/previous post links
    $links  = '<nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">';
    $links .= '<div class="nav-links">';
    $links .= $previous_title;
    $links .= $next_title;
    $links .= '</div><!-- .nav-links -->';
    $links .= '</nav><!-- .navigation -->';

    // Returns the post links with HTML mark-up
    return $links;

}

/** 
 * This function is simply just a wrapper for the main navigation
 * function and echo's the returned values from the main navigation
 * function
*/ 
function single_post_navigation( $args = [] ) {

    echo get_single_post_navigation( $args );

}
```

### USAGE IN SINGLE TEMPLATES

If you do not need to navigate posts within the same term, and custom next and previous text with your link, you can do the following

```
$args = [
    'post_types'       => ['post', 'my_cpt'],
    'in_same_term'     => false,
    'previous_text'      => __( 'Vorige Pos' ),
    'next_text'      => __( 'Volgende Pos' ),
];

single_post_navigation( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have another issue though. My posts are often in multiple categories. For example, a post can be in subject A and difficulty Z. Suppose I would like posts to appear in the next-posts link whose subject is also subject A. However, I don't want to be limited to difficulty Z. Is there any way to do that? It seems that with the way the arguments of the single_post_navigation are constructed. There is no way to pick a specific category if your post is in multiple categories. Also does this function work with custom post types (i.e only display other posts custom post type B).

Comment: I don't think there are any easy method when posts are in multiple categories. You will need to either a.) save the post's categories in some kind of transient, or b.) use the same method I have used in my code, but honestly, this can get bulky. I still need to add support for multiple post types. Will post an update soon on that

Comment: Code updated. Added `post_types` argument which is an array of post types

Comment: Just want to give an update that I implemented this code (with some modification to suit my purposes - not very much modification though) and it works really great Thanks so much for posting this answer.